# Jquery Mobile Pass and Retrieve Data with single page template

Tags: jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile

I have created a listview using data from a json request. The listview populates and I would like to click the listview item and go to a more detailed page. I need to retrieve the value.id1 for the clicked list item on #page4. I am using the single page jquery mobile template. I know the method below is not correct but hopefully it gives some idea of what I am trying to accomplish. What is the best method to pass data (value.id1) to another page from the list using the single page model of jquery mobile?

```
     $("#podList").click(function(){

        var listHtml ="<li>Select a date</li>"; 
        var driverid = $("#driverid").val();
        var url = "podHistory.php"
        $.post(url,{ driver: driverid } , function(response){
        var json = $.parseJSON(response);


        $.each(json, function(key, value){  

             listHtml += "<li><a href='#page4?=" + value.id1 + "'>" + value.date + "</a></li>";

            });//end each

    $("#history").html(listHtml); 
    $('ul').listview('refresh');

        });//end post podlist

        });//end pod list click 

   $("#page4").on("pagebeforeshow", function () { 

    var page = $(this);
    var query = page.data("url").split("?")[1];
    var id = query.split("=")[1];
    // console.log(id);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the **value.id1** in a data attribute and grab it as you click.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/5hzxqmpf/

**Html**

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist">
 <li data-id="1">Row 1</li>
 <li data-id="2">Row 2</li>
 <li data-id="3">Row 3</li>
 <li data-id="4">Row 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
var rowid;

$(document).on("click", "#mylist >li", function() {
rowid = $(this).closest("li").attr("data-id");
alert(rowid);;    
})
```